# Using service, ngResource save

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular.
I have this Service(?) for my RESTful services.

```
    .factory('LanguagesService', function ($resource) {
   return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/language/:langId', {
       langId: '@id'
   });
});
```

Then in my controller I do like this

```
adminLang.addLanguage = function () {
        LanguagesService.save({
            code: adminLang.newCode,
            name: adminLang.newName
        });
    }
```

My question is, how do I know if the `save()` is successful? So I can do this or that depending on if it fails or succeeds?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request add two callback functions as below:

```
LanguagesService.save({
            code: adminLang.newCode,
            name: adminLang.newName
        }, function(response){
           // success
        }, function(error){
           // error
        });
```

Check this for more information: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html

Answer (score 1):

`$resource` methods returns a `promise` object via `$promise` object, you could keep eye on that `promise` by placing `.then`.

**Code**

```
LanguagesService.save({
    code: adminLang.newCode,
    name: adminLang.newName
}).$promise.then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
   //do other awesome things
}, function(err){
});
```